# Writing command line argument parsers

Tags: parsing, language-agnostic, command-line-arguments

There are many well known command line argument parsers, like argp or a subset of boost::program_options for C++.

E.g., I recently tried to wrote one that let me parse simple scenarios in C++ like this:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    auto state = parse (argc, argv);
    const auto foo  = mandatory<int>            (state, {'f', "foo"});
    const auto bar  = optional_with_default<int>(state, {'b', "bar"}, 42);
    const auto frob = optional<std::string>     (state, {'F', "frob"});
    if (!frob) {
        ...
    }
}
```

but soon discovered that parsing position independent flags is not trivial (e.g. `-fgx` would be the same as `-f -xg`), then throwing position independent flags with value args in the mix became really non trivial (e.g. `tar -xvzf frob.tar.gz`).

The problems became obvious by empiricism only; I didn't find anything for example for this search.

Do you know any good resources on the topic? What are your own best practices?

---

Note: Even though I am naming some C++ examples, this question is ought to be language-agnostic. I am asking for algorithms and general suggestions.

Comment: I know that questions should _generally_ cover specific problems. But this one is really difficult stuff for self-research, so please take into account the ___generally___ in the FAQ's _but if your question __generally__ covers … a specific programming problem_

Comment: As someone commented (and of course quickly deleted so I don't see it) `Apache Commons CLI Enjoy it. Please pay more attention to self-search.`: I am looking for information about constructing such parsers, because I a find the existing ones tedious to use. I am __not__ looking for a parser :)

Comment: Why do you need to mix option declaration and option arguments? I think that will hurt usage, creating a lot of corner cases. After all, what is wrong with `tar -xvf file`?

Comment: @Rogach: See my answer. The example you show is already mixing flags (x, v) with short-options (f <filename>). The pain comes when `tar` allows `tar -xvffile`, without the space. Parsing flags might mean to remove letters from the filename.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant - why do you need that part without the space? Just treat every construction of type "-someletters" as a list of one-letter options, and don't mix them with arguments. Or it is not possible in your situation?

Comment: Or, if you absolutely need to mix options and arguments, just consume the letters until you get to the letter, which requires an argument after it (that's how I did it in my cli parsing library).

Comment: @Rogach: I want to support the non-space variant because it is common on unix-like operating systems. Another prominent example includes `g++ foo.cpp -ofrob`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you are writing a command line parser without having a declarative part (like in the example), and which allows for grouping of flags/short-options (`-xf` would be the same as `-x -f`), you somehow have to enforce an ordering of client calls.

Consider e.g. (assuming it is a valid invocation of the unix `tar` program):

```
tar -vfxul.tar -x
```

here you have the following options:

```
x
v
f=xul.tar
```

If you first test for the `x` flag (p-code),

```
state = parse(argc, argv)
x_set = flag (state, 'x')
...
filename = mandatory (state, 'f' or "filename")
```

you get into trouble answering the quesion: Which `x`?

```
tar -vfxul.tar -x
       ^        ^
       x?       x?
```

Because the parser does not yet know about the `filename` option, it may assume that in `vfxul.tar`, every single char (`v`, `x`, `u`, ...) might be a flag to be recognized.

So I think your best possible guess (without resorting to simple artificial intelligence or some complicated heuristics) now is to just take the first appearance of `x`.

I believe you should forbid to parse any flag-options after a short-option-with-value has been parsed:

```
state = parse(argc, argv)
x_set = flag (state, 'x')
...
filename = mandatory (state, 'f' or "filename") // THROW ERROR HERE!
```

This forces you into a situation where you have to crunch your code into a certain order, which even more reduces the applicability of such library, so this is really only for a very simple-situation-parser where you have a non-interdependent argument list.

Note: You only need to reorder your parsings where short-options are possible or when flag-/short-option grouping is allowed.

---

#### Sources

- Empricism